# Depending on data attribute how to Hide the tag and display in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

This is the for each loop to render the data

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: PersonData, as: 'ref' }">
       <li>
           <a data-bind="attr: { data: ref.Filter }" class="filterbtn">
               <span data-bind="html: ref.Name"></span>
               <span data-bind="text: ref.Age" class="age"></span>
           </a>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to hide  if data attribute value is `data="people"`  and display it in another div.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `display it in another div` you mean to display outside `ul` tag ? or ?. sample fiddle is appreciated

Comment: @super cool yes display  outside ul tag

Comment: try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25260/ . let me know so i can post as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a computed setup to make things working

**view:**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: PersonData}">
    <li> <a data-bind="attr: { data: Filter },visible:Filter!='people'" class="filterbtn">
               <span data-bind="html: Name"></span>
               <span data-bind="text: Age" class="age"></span>
           </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="foreach:data"> <span data-bind="html: Name"></span>
 <span data-bind="text: Age" class="age"></span>
</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.PersonData = ko.observableArray([{
        'Filter': 'people',
        'Name': 'cool',
        'Age': '1'
    }, {
        'Filter': 'nope',
        'Name': 'cooler',
        'Age': '2'
    }, {
        'Filter': 'people',
        'Name': 'hotter',
        'Age': '3'
    }])

    self.data = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.PersonData(), function (item) {
            return item.Filter === "people"; //do a case check here(if)
        });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working fiddle up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25260/)**